# JQuery validator & qTip2 - Does not get hidden after success

Tags: jquery, html, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, qtip2

I've been struggling around with both libraries to get working together and am nearly finished now, finally!

At first I tried the normal, proposed way:

1. Create the form
2. Set validation rules via `escaped name attributes`, as `RoR` automatically sets all form name-attributes like this: `user[name]`.

This wouldn't work, because I don't know why. JavaScript simply wouldn't recognize the attribute `"user[name]"` with the square brackets.

Then I tried it another way and added the rules dynamically. This is a code snippet how my validation looks like now:

**Form:**

```
<form id="form" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="user[username]" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {

    $("input[name='user[username]']").rules("add", {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3,
      maxlength: 20,
      messages: {
        required: "U better fill dis out!",
        minlength: "Hey, minimum of 3 letters!",
        maxlength: "U wanna fuck wis me? I no can read dat much!"
      }
    })

    $('#form').validate({
      debug: true,
      validClass: 'valid',
      errorClass: 'error',
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

        // qTip call
        if (!$(element).hasClass('valid')) {
          if (error.html() != "") {
            $(element).qtip({
              content: {
                text: error.html()
              },
              position: {
                my: 'left center',
                at: 'right center',
                target: $(element)
              },
              show: {
                when: false,
                ready: true
              },
              hide: false
            });
          }
        }
      },
      success: function(label, element) {
        // Hide tooltips on valid elements
        $(element).not('.error').qtip('hide');
      },
      highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
      },
      unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
      }
    });

});
```

Now imagine the following scenario:

1. I'm writing something into this text field, like only 1 letter
2. `qTip` shows my validation message which tells me: "*Minimum of 3 letters required.*"
3. Now I'll fix the problem and input 4 letters. All validations should pass now.
4. When I move and click outside the input field, the `qTip` will disappear.
5. When I click inside the input field again, the old `qTip` will show again, saying "*Minimum of 3 letters required.*". But there are 4 letters inside. **Why is it still showing?**

**EDIT:**

This is the html output, after `Step 5`

```
<input aria-describedby="qtip-22" data-hasqtip="22" class="valid" name="user[username]" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Well, now I'm feeling super dumb and like a king at the same time.

The solution was pretty easy. Instead of hiding the qTip, simply remove it when validation succeeded.

```
...
success: function(label, element) {
    // Destroy tooltips on valid elements
    $(element).not('.error').qtip('destroy');
}
...
```